# How do I create a Window in App B so that App A may use it to render instead of using it's own Window

Tags: c++, winapi

Folks, I apologize if this sounds like a newbie questions, but I am not very familiar with Windows development as a whole. So I was given App A, which does a lot of things and one particular function is to render a duck picture. Internally it created the Window with the title 'DrawingBoard' and later on when the program is ready to render it will try to find this "DrawingBoard" window. I was only told that this is how App A finds the window to render the duck:

```
     static const TCHAR TITLE_NAME[] = "DrawingBoardParent";   
     static const TCHAR TITLE_CLASS_NAME[] = "DrawingBoard";

     HWND parent = FindWindowExA(NULL, NULL, NULL, TITLE_NAME);
     while (parent != NULL)
     {
        //find the child window by window title
        window = findWindowRecursive(parent, TITLE_CLASS_NAME);
        if (window != NULL)
        {
           break;
        }
        //no child by the given title name found, go down one level
        parent = FindWindowExA(NULL, parent, NULL, TITLE_NAME);
     }
```

Now I need to create App B and I want to create my own "DrawingBoard" window on App B. Because App A uses the above algorithm to find the rendering window, instead of using it's own App A "DrawingBoard" Window, it will use my App B "DrawingBoard" Window.

Questions:

1) Is this within the realm of possibility at all ?
2) Say if both App A & B have two windows with the same title "DrawingBoard". Which one does FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, ""DrawingBoard"); return ?
3) If FindWindowEx always returns the handle for App A "DrawingBoard" window. How do I hack it so it will return App B "DrawingBoard" window.

Thanks for the help folks.

Comment: You need to fix App A which is utterly broken.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the source code for App A :(

Comment: So you have to remove the defective app, or use a different window name

Comment: [Windows have thread affinity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/10/479124.aspx). Modifying a window from a thread other than the one that created it is asking for trouble. This can be made to work, if you are intimately familiar with the window manager, and control both applications. Since you do not control one of the applications, you will have to look for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Say if both App A & B have two windows with the same title `"DrawingBoard"`. Which one does `FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, ""DrawingBoard")` return?

That is ill-defined. It will return one of them. You cannot influence which is returned.

> If FindWindowEx always returns the handle for App A "DrawingBoard" window. How do I hack it so it will return App B "DrawingBoard" window.

You cannot. The other app is broken. Its search for a window that it created is broken, since it can yield the wrong window, a window from another process.

You can avoid getting caught out by this app by using a different name for your window. However you really ought to either fix or remove the defective program. That's the sane way forward.